# Always trigger handler execution in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to provision my development server.

I want it to always start some services for me. I have handlers for this purpose but what is the best way to trigger handler execution without condition, e.g. make it always work?

Something like this:

```
tasks:
    - name: Trigger handler
      run_handler: name=nginx-restart
```

Comment: If you want a task to always run you should make it a task rather than a handler.

Comment: @Jordan - sometimes you may want to have a handler that's conditionally triggered in most scenarios except this particular one.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you absolutely need to trigger a handler every time then here are two options:

1)  run a noop shell command which will always report as changed

```
-  name: trigger nginx-restart
   command: /bin/true
   notify: nginx-restart
```

2)  use debug along with [changed_when:](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result) to trigger a handler

```
-  debug: msg="trigger nginx-restart"
   notify: nginx-restart
   changed_when: true
```

Also of [note](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_checkmode.html) for Option 1 and Check Mode: You may want to use `check_mode: no` if using Ansible version 2.2 or higher or `always_run: yes` if using earlier versions than that so that the task does not get skipped over in check mode. From my manual testing it looks like the handlers remain in check mode, but please be careful as your case may differ.

Comment: Nowadays, you can `  --force-handlers      run handlers even if a task fails`

Comment: Yes though that will force all handlers to run

Comment: i found this post useful regarding the changed status, that lead me here.  https://serverfault.com/a/799282/173002.  ty.

Comment: Thanks, I used option 2 and a `changed_when` with more logic in it to implement a non-idempotent task [which may be invoked more than once in some cases] as a handler rather than a task.

Comment: For me a combination of both options did it, as I needed the task itself to check a variable using `when`. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

### Ansible provides several options for forcing handlers:

1. To always force all handlers, run `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --force-handlers`, as documented here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4777
2. To force handlers that have been notified at a specific point within a playbook, you can use a meta task https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html:

```
    tasks: 
      - shell: some tasks go here
      - meta: flush_handlers
      - shell: some other tasks
```

3. However, it sounds like you just want to make sure a service is running or restarted, regardless of the outcome of another task. In that case, don't use a handler, use a new task that calls Ansible's `service` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html

```
    tasks: 
      - name: ensure ntp is running
        service: name=ntp state=started enabled=yes

      - name: always reload nginx
        service: name=nginx state=reloaded

      - name: always restart MySQL
        service: name=mysql state=restarted
```

Comment: The problem with (3) is that one might have several tasks which notify the handler, and I don't want the handler to run (restarting the service) several times.

Comment: Multiple tasks can notify the same handler, and the handler will only execute once. That's the whole point of handlers.

Comment: Hey Jeff. This answer is about not using handlers, specifying all actions just using tasks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I still don't understand the use case you're trying to solve for... Maybe open a new question with an example of what you're trying to accomplish? If you add a comment with a link to it I'll try to answer it.

Comment: I don't need a new question. The OQ asked "How can I make sure a handler ALWAYS runs", and this answer, part 3, suggested "Use tasks instead", and my comment points out "Your task might then run several times in some circumstances."

Comment: I believe the documentation you refer to in issue #4777 is incorrect: `--force-handlers` does not unconditionally run all handlers. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327595/29483 The behaviour of `--force-handlers`, which is correctly documented nearly everywhere else e.g. in the man page and the ansible user guide, is that *notified* handlers will be run even if the play stops early due to a failed task.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Have you found a solution that ensures a service runs without restarting it (again) when handlers run?

Comment: @wedi I did not.

Answer (score 11):

Restarting a service is one thing; ensuring it is running is another. If you want `ansible` to make sure `nginx` is running, you do this:

```
tasks:
  - name: Ensure nginx is running
    service: name=nginx state=started
```