# Why is ansible notify not working?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm learning ansible and wrote simple playbook, but I don't understand or what I'm doing wrong that handler not working! Please, help me.

My playbook:

```
- hosts: HA
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Installs pacemaker
      yum: pkg=pacemaker,pcs,resource-agents state=latest
      notify:
         - pcsd start

  handlers:
    - name: pcsd start
      systemd: name=pcsd state=started
```

He skipped notify:

```
PLAY [HA] **********************************************************************

TASK [Installs pacemaker] ******************************************************
ok: [test-ha2]
ok: [test-ha1]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
test-ha1                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
test-ha2                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 28):

Handlers will only be fired for tasks which report a `changed` state. In the output of your play you can see the status is `ok`, which in this case means no new packages have been installed or updated (since state=latest)

So it would work, if any of the packages would not have been installed already.

Though, instead of state `started` I would use state `restarted`, since you're always upgrading to the latest packages in your task (state=latest) If a package gets updated, you also should restart the service.